# I am still pushing to a deleted branch in github. What is going on?

Tags: git

So I wanted to rename my branches in github with numbers to show the order of my branches. I wrote a tutorial and I had different branches for my students to clone down. This is what I did:

1. I renamed the branch locally:

   ```
   git remote -m setting-up-rails-api 1-setting-up-rails-api
   ```
2. I deleted the remote old branch name:

   ```
   git push origin :setting-up-rails-api
   ```
3. I want to push the new branch name to github with this:

   ```
   git push -u origin 1-setting-up-rails-api
   ```

But it creates the old branch on GitHub.

```
git push -u origin 1-setting-up-rails-api
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 461 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:andela/rails-api-practice.git
 * [new branch]      1-setting-up-rails-api -> setting-up-rails-api
Branch 1-setting-up-rails-api set up to track remote branch setting-up-rails-api from origin.
```

I wanted to check my upstreams:

```
git branch -vv
* 1-setting-up-rails-api            85fd6df [origin/setting-up-rails-api] editing readme again
  2-unit-testing-models-and-bottles 832a4cb fixing errors in tutorial
  3-creating-an-api                 955f721 fixing errors in tutorial
  4-testing-api                     5e62371 fixing errors in tutorial
  5-serialize-dat-suya              055769e finishing up readme
  master                            6868b7c changing readme
```

My origin:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:andela/rails-api-practice.git
```

I am not sure why I am still pushing to the deleted branch and thus recreating the old branch on the remote. I don't want to do that. I want to just push the new branch up to the remote. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In step 1, did you mean `git branch -m`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
git push -u origin 1-setting-up-rails-api:1-setting-up-rails-api
```

Despite what you may believe, the branch name in `git push <remote> <branch>` refers to your *local* branch. So this will make Git lookup the origin branch name and push to that.

You can overwrite that by specifying it with `<localbranch>:<remotebranch>`. With the `-u` this should also update your configuration, so following `git push` should all use that new name.

Answer (score 0):

Following your steps works for me, so I'm not sure what caused the problem. If @poke's solution still doesn't work (it should), you can manually fix it with a quick edit to `.git/config`. Find the section starting with your branch name, which will look something like:

```
[branch "1-setting-up-rails-api"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/setting-up-rails-api
    rebase = true
```

Change the `merge` line to

```
    merge = refs/heads/1-setting-up-rails-api
```

`git push` again, and the new remote branch will be created.

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to do this first:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```